# python remove div if text matches

Tags: html, python-2.7

I'm scraping a website using **scrapy** and there is a html structure as:

```
<div>
  <div class = "mydiv">abc</div>
  <div class = "mydiv">xyz</div>
  <div class = "mydiv">ghi</div>
</div>
```

If the text inside the div matches to **xyz**, i want to remove div including the one containing the text and all other div that follows it. I've successfully extracted the text in each div using xpath. Is there anyway i can achieve this in python.

Since the text inside the second div matched the required text **xyz**, second and third div needs to be deleted
My final output thenwould be:

```
<div>
  <div class = "mydiv">abc</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: show your expected output.

Comment: @user1153551 there you go

Comment: No I am here, wait for while

Comment: I made https://www.regex101.com/r/pE8eX8/1 I can't find to select until last occurance </div>.